# No transactional EntityManager found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, testing

I have looked for simillar questions here on stackoverflow, but it seems like everyone has different problems occuring due to lack of understanding how spring does transactions for you.
Well, I am writing some test for endpoints. First I made a higher order class to populate with class for each endpoint I have. I still think it's supposed to only serve as a method of logical separation, so that it's easier to distinguish between each other and not test directory with tons of different files. But it might be not that way:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@Rollback(false)
public class EndpointTest {
    User user, user2;
    Item card, token;
    AuctionLot auctionLot;
    Bid bid;

    TestEntityManager testEntityManager;
    UserRepository userRepository;
    CardRepository cardRepository;
    TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    AuctionLotRepository auctionLotRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EndpointTest(TestEntityManager testEntityManager, UserRepository userRepository,
            TokenRepository tokenRepository, CardRepository cardRepository, AuctionLotRepository auctionLotRepository) {
        this.testEntityManager = testEntityManager;
        this.cardRepository = cardRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
        this.auctionLotRepository = auctionLotRepository;

        User user = new User("user1", "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", "example@gmail.com", RoleEnum.USER),
                user2 = new User("user2", "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA", "example1@gmail.com",
                        RoleEnum.USER);
        Token token = new Token(BigInteger.valueOf(1l), "someuri", "addressFactory", "addressNFT", "token1",
                "Some token", BigInteger.valueOf(100l), user);
        testEntityManager.persist(user);
        testEntityManager.persist(user2);
        testEntityManager.persist(token);
        testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(new Card("card1", "someurl", "Some card", new Date(), token));
    }

    @Nested
    public class CurrencyExchangeEndpointTest {
        @Autowired
        private CurrencyExchangeEndpoint endpoint;

        @Test
        public void exchangeEthToGoldCoinTest() {
            endpoint.exchangeEthToGoldCoin(BigInteger.valueOf(100l), user.getId());
            assertEquals(userRepository.findByProfileUsername(user.getUsername()).getWallet().getBalanceGoldCoin(),
                    100L);
        }

        @Test
        public void exchangeGExtraToEthTest() {
            user.getWallet().addBalanceGExtra(BigInteger.valueOf(100l));
            userRepository.save(user);
            endpoint.exchangeGExtraToEth(BigInteger.valueOf(40l), user.getId());
            assertEquals(userRepository.findByProfileUsername(user.getUsername()).getWallet().getBalanceGExtra(), 60l);
        }
    }
...
}
```

I purposefully added @Rollback(false) for convenience, because it's obvious to me how to work with side-effects of each test (it's some sort of end-to-end test I think). But there's an error, and it's has to be peace of a cake, but I just have no clue what should I do in order to fix this. I tried removing rollback annotation, but it didn't help. Does it have something to do with nesting? Error messages are the same for all tests:

```java
EndpointTest > CurrencyExchangeEndpointTest > exchangeGExtraToEthTest() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager found, is your test running in a transaction?
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.getEntityManager(TestEntityManager.java:237)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.persist(TestEntityManager.java:92)
        at com.suplab.suplabethereum.controller.EndpointTest.<init>(EndpointTest.java:66)
...
```

Tests outside of this file work just fine, so that has to be something wrong with coonfiguration I guess.

Comment: DataJpaTest already has a transactional annotation. why don't you remove rollback annotation?

Comment: @JoonseoLee I guess I could? And I tried, but I want my test not to rollback db state, because I use side-effects in other tests. In one test, I add some cash to user, and in other I use that cash to interact with market.

Comment: @JoonseoLee yeah, once again I removed the annotation and it failed with the same error. Most likely it's not about this annotation.

Comment: @JoonseoLee if you think that it is a bad idea, maybe you could suggest a better solution for this task?

Comment: ahh I didn't get the point. well in my point of view, I just create unit test without db connections. because I just want to check the logic in the unit test. so to satisfy your expectation I have to offer other solutions,

Comment: @JoonseoLee I think that it's more like integration test because main purpose of this test is to check if endpoints and services work fine together.. but maybe I could just have checked if services to what they are supposed to do?